# Image for Canvas is not created

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-3.6, tkinter-canvas

So I want a window that updates a shown picture after clicking.
It works fine as long as there is no further `tk.Tk()` instance (remove/add line 8 of the code below).

If one is created before, this error is raised:

```
line 29, in CreatePeakSelectionWindow
[...]
self.imgCanvas.create_image((0,0),anchor=tk.NW,image=self.img1)
[...]
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

I think I need to pass some argument to `Tk()`?
I don't know where to even look to address this issue and understand how it is caused.
Sadly this widget is to be used to allow manual selection of some peaks and should be done in an external window.
FYI all arrays are dummies (random arrays) for simplicities sake.

Thank you very much for any help!

The code which causes the issue is the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MainWin = tk.Tk() #>this line causes the issue
        imgs = np.random.randint(0,255,(512,624,2))
        self.img = imgs[:,:,0] #self.img is a numpy array in black and white
        self.imgSize = self.img.shape
        self.peakList = np.array([[200,200],[300,400]])
        self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList = []
        self.peakListGenerated = True

    def CreatePeakSelectionWindow(self):
        if self.peakListGenerated:
            self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList = []
            self.PeakSelectionWindow = tk.Tk()
            self.PeakSelectionWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.PeakSelectionWindowClose)
            self.PeakSelectionWindow.geometry("%sx%s"%(self.imgSize[1],self.imgSize[0]))
            self.PeakSelectionWindow.title("Peak Slection")
            self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(self.img))
            self.imgCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.PeakSelectionWindow,width=self.imgSize[1],height=self.imgSize[0])
            self.imgCanvas.place(x=0,y=0)
            self.PeakSelectionWindow.bind("<Button 1>",self.LeftClick)
            self.PeakSelectionWindow.bind("<Button 3>",self.RightClick)
            self.PeakSelectionWindow.update()
            self.imgCanvas.create_image((0,0),anchor=tk.NW,image=self.img1)
        else:
            print("List of peaks has not yet been generated!",file=sys.stderr)

    def PeakSelectionWindowClose (self):
        if len(self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList) > 0:
            print("put extraction here")
            #self.selectedPeaksEntry.insert(tk.END,", ".join(map(str,self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList)))
        self.PeakSelectionWindow.destroy()

    def LeftClick(self,event):
        distance = np.sqrt((self.peakList[:,1]-event.x)**2+(self.peakList[:,0]-event.y)**2)
        index = np.argmin(distance)
        if index not in self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList:
            self.peakList[index]
            self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList += [index]
            newImg = np.random.randint(0,255,(self.img.shape[0],self.img.shape[1],3))
            self.PeakSelectionWindow.newImg = img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(newImg.astype("uint8"),mode="RGB"))
            self.imgCanvas.delete("all")
            self.imgCanvas.create_image((0,0),anchor=tk.NW,image=self.PeakSelectionWindow.newImg)
            self.imgCanvas.update()

    def RightClick (self,event):
        distance = np.sqrt((self.peakList[:,1]-event.x)**2+(self.peakList[:,0]-event.y)**2)
        index = np.argmin(distance)
        print(self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList)
        if index in self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList:
            if len(self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList) > 1:
                self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList.remove(index)
                newImg = np.random.randint(0,255,(self.img.shape[0],self.img.shape[1],3))
                self.PeakSelectionWindow.newImg = img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(newImg.astype("uint8"),mode="RGB"))
                self.imgCanvas.delete("all")
                self.imgCanvas.create_image((0,0),anchor=tk.NW,image=self.PeakSelectionWindow.newImg)
                self.imgCanvas.update()
            else:
                self.selectedIndexOfPeaksList = []
                self.PeakSelectionWindow.newImg = newImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(self.img.astype("uint8")))
                self.imgCanvas.delete("all")
                self.imgCanvas.create_image((0,0),anchor=tk.NW,image=self.PeakSelectionWindow.newImg)
                self.imgCanvas.update()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Dummy()
    window.CreatePeakSelectionWindow()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution.
The additional window needs to be a class with `tk.Toplevel()`.
All changes for the code above are:

- `class Dummy:` to `class Dummy (tk.Toplevel()):`
- `def __init__(self):` to `def __init__ (self,master):`
- `self.peakSelectionWindow` to `self` (as a reference to `master`
  passed to the class)
- any `tk` object (like buttons) also needs this `master` set as the window too to be rendered

Of course the creation of the first window should be handled outside of the class, passing the `windowName = tk.Tk()` onto the call of `Dummy` like a normal variable/reference.

In case you need to share variables of the master to this dummy class, I think `windowName.variableName = 5` makes them known/accessable in dummy too (via `self.variableName`). However this might be messy, so instead pass them on normally if possible.

Comment: Also here is a link to a German forum post that has the above solution in working code:
[link](https://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?t=30286)

Be aware `Tkinter` is now `tkinter`